# Blocking up an unused door with timber / cladding. How to protect from weather and insulate?

Tags: doors, blocking

I have a rotting backdoor that forms a side entrance to a conservatory. The door is never used. I plan to take out the door, build a timber frame where the door frame and sill was, and then install some good marine ply to do the bulk of the covering.

On the inside of the ply, I then want to fill behind with insulation board, and plasterboard over.

On the exterior side of the ply, I want to cover with exterior timber cladding and paint.

The questions are:

Is that a reasonable solution (if I want to avoid brick laying) and is there anything further I can do to weather protect the ply under the cladding?

Thanks

Comment: Marine-grade plywood isn't normally used for wall sheathing. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: Assuming you're not concerned about matching the rest of the exterior wall, fastest and easiest might be to buy a new insulated door and just nail it in place, fill the seams with caulk, and be done.

Comment: @isherwood I assumed because it would be exposed to some moisture under the cladding. Is this incorrect?

Comment: I agree with Isherwood don’t wast $ on marine grade. They use the same glue the difference is marine grade has smaller knots and any holes on the core sheets are plugged. You do not need that, I would use a tyvek or other type of house wrap over the plywood , then house wrap then siding. Make sure you remove any rotted framing in the current opening. Other than that your plan sounds good.

Comment: Sounds like an answer, Ed.

Comment: Thanks Ed, +1 for the house wrap (or vapour barrier as I found it called if that's the same stuff)

Comment: Do you have another back door that is used? ie if the main door were blocked for some reason, could you get out elsewhere in an emergency if you were in the conservatory? If not, you might want to re-consider eliminating that door.

Comment: @peinal - yes there is another door. This room is more of a cupboard than a room, hence the external door never being used.